# Extracting data from Boxplot on Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I have the Boxplot for a certain attribute but is there a way to extract mean, median, mode, and midrange, variance etc from Boxplots i.e is there a command that does this easily.

```
   sns.boxplot(x = 'Pos',y = 'BLK', data=dataset) .
```

Comment: you mean drawing a line in the boxplot to show mean, median?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe name is dataset, you can use

```
dataset.describe()
```

this gives mean, mode and other summary statistics.

if you want to divide this by groups, use:

```
dataset.groupby('variable_to_be_grouped').describe().
```

here is an example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5],'x2':[2,4,6,8,10], 'x3':['a','a','a','b','b']})

x.groupby('x3').describe()
```